# app created using xamarin will be webapp or actual native ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xamarin

I know I should have not asked this here, but I want to collect views of all.

I want to create app using Xamarin.

***Will this app will be actual iPhone app or web app?*** *I don't want to have app like created using PhoneGap or Titanium.*

Comment: Xamarin - is a database ,it only support for backend data storage

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : whatsapp me @ +965 65810617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be an iPhone app. It works as follows:

> Our Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compiler compiles Xamarin.iOS apps directly to
>   native ARM assembly code, meaning your app is a native platform
>   binary.

Thus, your app will be built as an `.ipa` once compiled which in turn can be uploaded to the AppStore.

You can even access all of Apple's iOS SDK using Xamarin.iOS.

You can read more [here](https://xamarin.com/platform).

Comment: Sounds great... I will check the link provided... One more question... Can I export the code in xcode? Or only Binary is what I will get at the end?

Comment: What do you mean by "export the code in xcode"? Do you want to use existing Objective-C code using Xamarin?

Comment: No.. Let's say I create project using Xamarin.. Now i want to get the code in Objective-C... So I can update using xcode... Or I have to update in xamarin only?

Comment: No, you cannot. Whereas Xamarin apps are written using C#, iOS apps are written using Objective-C. The Objective-C interpreter does not compile C# in XCode. What you could do is to write a wrapper in Objective-C and bind it in your Xamarin project as explained [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/).

But why would you want to transition between the two in the first place? Seems like a bad idea.